# Pydantic RootModel data

Tags: python, pydantic

In the docs https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types,

The examples mention how to get items in a RootModel list.
If I wanted to get the list itself, how should I do it?

```
Pets = RootModel[list[str]]
pets = Pets(['dog', 'cat'])
print(pets.root)  # This will directly print the list: ['dog', 'cat']
```

It feels a bit weird and non-pythonic to have to do `.root`.
Is there a better way?

I am asking because I have something like this:

```
Pets = RootModel[list[str]]
class Foo(BaseModel):
    pets: Pets

foo = Foo(pets=Pets(['dog', 'cat']))
```

and if I want to get the pets, I need to do `foo.pets.root`.
I'd like to be able to do `foo.pets`.

Comment: Well, why don't you have `pets: list[str]` then?

Comment: that's a valid point but I'm just playing along with the documentation example. 
They use a RootModel to represent that `list[str]`. I can't imagine that getting the list itself has to be by doing a weird `.root`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach here is to make your root model look a bit more like a list by implementing "dunder" methods. This is shown in the Pydantic docs one paragraph further in the same section you linked to:

```py
from typing import List

from pydantic import RootModel


class Pets(RootModel):
    root: List[str]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.root)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.root[item]
```

This will allow to access items, iterate through the list, convert to a list etc.

I hope this helps!